# Problem with showing pie chart at the center of the page

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm still new in Flutter and I have a problem with centering pie chart. My mainAxisAlignment is set to center but it still show on start. Any ideas?

```
_buildBody() {
return SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        PieChart(
          dataMap: dataMap,
          animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
          chartLegendSpacing: 32,
          chartRadius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.2,
          colorList: colorList,
          initialAngleInDegree: 0,
          chartType: ChartType.ring,
          ringStrokeWidth: 32,
          centerText: "MY REQUESTS",
          legendOptions: const LegendOptions(
            showLegendsInRow: false,
            legendPosition: LegendPosition.bottom,
            showLegends: true,
            legendShape: BoxShape.circle,
            legendTextStyle: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          chartValuesOptions: const ChartValuesOptions(
            showChartValueBackground: true,
            showChartValues: true,
            showChartValuesInPercentage: false,
            showChartValuesOutside: false,
            decimalPlaces: 1,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

[image]

Comment: remove `SingleChildScrollView `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `SingleChildScrollView`. That is why `Center` is not working, because it is expanding all size of screen and children must be minimum size. Then your first child of `SingleChildScrollView` is `Column` sized it minumum size.

1. Column
2. SingleChildScrollView
3. Center

[image: here is picture]

---

###### For simple fix just remove SingleChildScrollView and Center widget and set Column aligns to center.

```
_buildBody() {
return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        PieChart(
          dataMap: dataMap,
          animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
          chartLegendSpacing: 32,
          chartRadius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.2,
          colorList: colorList,
          initialAngleInDegree: 0,
          chartType: ChartType.ring,
          ringStrokeWidth: 32,
          centerText: "MY REQUESTS",
          legendOptions: const LegendOptions(
            showLegendsInRow: false,
            legendPosition: LegendPosition.bottom,
            showLegends: true,
            legendShape: BoxShape.circle,
            legendTextStyle: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          chartValuesOptions: const ChartValuesOptions(
            showChartValueBackground: true,
            showChartValues: true,
            showChartValuesInPercentage: false,
            showChartValuesOutside: false,
            decimalPlaces: 1,
          ),
        ),
      ],
);
```